# Multithreading and Dialogs show/dismiss give exceptions in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, exception, dialog

I have Android application that creates several threads. Some threads use thread-safe HttpClient to get data from server continuously.

Example 1: thread 1 -> got data from server and now I must show Dialog to inform user.
Example 2: thread 2 -> (on UI-thread) show modal PendingDialog -> start thread 2 -> post data on server and check response (not on UI-thread) -> runOnUiThread() { dismissPendingDialog()...}

Basically I'm creating threads with:

```
classRunnableInstance = new MyRunnable(...);
classThreadInstance = new Thread(classRunnableInstance);
classThreadInstance.start();
```

And basic structure of "fetching" threads is:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while(shouldRun) {
            SomeResultObj result = MyHttpClient.invokeSomeMethod();
            if(checkIfIMustInformUser(result)) {
                inform();
            }
            sleep();
        }
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        activityGivenInConstructor.showFetchingDataError(e); //show on UI-thread
    }
}

protected void inform(final SomeResultObj result) {
    activityGivenInConstructor.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Dialog dialog = MyDialogUtils.create(context, messageId);
            ...
            dialog.show();
            //or pendingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    shouldRun = false;
    return;
}

protected void sleep() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(AppConstants.SLEEP_DELAY);
    }
    catch(InterruptedException e) {
        shouldRun = false;
    }
}
```

Also I'm stopping and starting threads in: `onPause()` and `onResume()` respectively.

I'm handling "show one dialog at a time" with success. But problem arises when user performs some actions - for example:

- Quits application
- Go to new activity
- Go to Home, etc.

When I show dialog (note: on UI-thread) there are sometimes exceptions like `WindowManager$BadTokenException`, `IllegalStateException`, `MyActivity has leaked window` etc.

I can check before `dialog.show()`:

```
if(!Thread.interrupted() && shouldRun && !activityGivenInConstructor.isFinishing())
```

but this resolves only exiting from application problem. Some exceptions are rised in other situations.

How should I implement this? That there would be no more exceptions?
And is this check/if(!Thread.interrupted()... all I can do to prevent rising exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

I am not an andriod developer, but I did some UI coding. Judging from the things you have posted, if the screen that the user current is in, doesn't require a modal dialog to be shown, shouldn't that be programatically handled? More specifically checkIfIMustInformUser(result) method call?

Comment: Consider that case: I pull data from server. This data can change in any time. For example `boolean`. If fetched `boolean` is `true` then I inform user about it, if it is `false` then nothing is happening and user can use this activity ("screen") without any distractions.